# UWP Itemscontrol - Get an item in viewport

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime

I have a list of items binded to an itemscontrol. I want to find the first visible item in the view port. How can I achieve this. In listView there is an method getFirstVisbibleItem(), but I don't want a listview here, I just need an itemscontrol.

Comment: Can't you use a ListView then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626096/uwp-listview-getfirstvisibleitem-bug

Comment: @JustinXL Please see the question mentioned in the  above  link. I have posted an example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: So did you mean if the previous issue resolved you will use `ListView`? The reason you are using use `ItemsControl` is because you are met the previous issue?

Comment: Yes its correct. Although listview is derived from Itemscontrol.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Is there a workaround for solving this issue.

Comment: Please update this issue with the details info in that thread. And I didn't find `GetFirstVisibleItem()` for a `ListView`, where is this method come from?

Comment: Details information about the issue is in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626096/uwp-listview-getfirstvisibleitem-bug GetFirstVisibleItem is a part of WinrtXamlToolkt extension from nugget package.

Comment: That thread has already been deleted by SO we cannot see that now. You need to update this thread to detail the issue since if there is a reply is for other thread may make people who visit this later confused. Thinks for understanding.